# QEMU: how to share guest VPN connection with host

Tags: networking, vpn, virtualization, qemu

I have a QEMU VM with Windows 10 from which I can connect to a VPN. I would like to connect also the guest system (GNU/Linux) to the VPN, but unfortunately the VPN works only on Windows.

I use `virt-manager` to manage my VM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here there is a solution for virtualbox: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53573337/how-to-share-guest-vms-vpn-connection-with-host

It could be easily adapted for QEMU following https://brockmcelroy.com/kvm-host-only and https://serverfault.com/questions/929081/how-can-i-enable-packet-forwarding-on-windows

1. Create a Windows VM with `virt-manager`
2. On `virt-manager` main window right click on `QEMU/KVM` → Deatils → Add newtwork (`+`)

   - name: `host-only`
   - mode: `Isolated`
   - IPv4 config:

     - Network: `192.168.56.0/24`
3. In the VM hardware details of `virt-manager` press `Add hardware` below → Network

   - Network source: the previosly created `host-only` isolated network
4. Reboot the host (the Unix-like machine)
5. In the guest (the Windows VM) open the registry editor and under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters` edit/create the `DWORD` `IPEnableRouter` setting it to `1`
6. Reboot the guest
7. In the guest open `Network & Internet Settings` → `Network and Sharing Center`.
   Here there are two networks: the NAT one (with internet access) and the host-only one (without internet access): open the latter → Properties → Internet Protocol Version 4 (TCP/IPv4) → Properties

   - IP address: `192.168.56.2`
8. Install on the guest the VPN and connect to it
9. In the guest open `Network & Internet Settings` → `Network and Sharing Center`.
   Open the VPN network → Properties → Sharing → Allow with the host-only network
10. In the host run `ip route add xxx.yyy.zzz.www/qq via 192.168.56.2` with sudo (where `xxx.yyy.zzz.www/qq` is the network you want to access through the VPN)

#### On guest restart

- Check the IP of the host-only network to be correct (step 7 above)
- Disbale the sharing of the VPN network and re-enable it (step 9 above), after connecting to the VPN